# React how not to display if doing calculation inside jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am inside a map, and I am calulating how many items exist for each category.

I am then setting its value to a property. This works fine.
The issue is it also shows that value on the screen, which I don't want.

```
               {
                  (tab.itemCount = props.items.filter(
                    (item) => item.category === tab.category
                  ).length)
                }
```

How can I do this calculation inside the JSX without it also showing the length value on the screen?

Comment: Why does it need to be in the JSX and not just higher up in the component?

Comment: it's inside a block like this:  {props.tabs?.map((tab) => (

I guess it would just save me duplicating code

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the case here, might help if you include more code. But my recommendation is going to be to do the calculation in the non-JSX area of your component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would be to put this logic not directly inside the JSX, but at the point where `tab.itemCount` is used. Perhaps at the top level of the component, or directly inside the `render` method if you're using a class component?

(Though, assigning to `tab.itemCount` in the first place also sounds like a mistake, because that would be a mutation of the `tab` object, and mutation of state and props should always be avoided in React, else you'll often run into problems)

If you really had to do something like this - which I'd highly recommend against - you could use the comma operator, or an IIFE that doesn't return anything.

```
{
    (() => {
        tab.itemCount = props.items.filter(
            (item) => item.category === tab.category
        ).length);
    })()
}
```